# 404 error on product pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product, 404-page

When I click on the product in the store, it will return a 404 error page.
I check with adding new products but the result is same. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Category url is working?

Comment: did u try reindex

Comment: @Kothari, I tried it but it's not working

Comment: @PrashantValanda, Yeah the category url is working but the product url is not working

Comment: What's the error while reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by compilation process.
System>Tools>Compilation.